# How to view cvs commit history if server no longer exists?

Tags: cvs

I have a local copy of an old cvs depo that contains the `CVS` folders. The cvs server no longer exists. Is it possible to view the commit history and comments for the changes that were made in the depo? Would I have to e.g. migrate the depo to git or a newer version control system before I can do this?

I tried installing SmartCVS and using it to view the logs, but when I do SmartCVS still attempts to contact the server, fails, and shows me nothing.

Is there a way to view any kind of history logs using only what I have locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a `*,v` file, then you can view the history with rlog.  Remember that cvs is just a wrapper around RCS, so all the standard RCS commands will work with your cvs files.  (Read the manpages for `ci`, `co`, `rlog`, `rcs`, `rcsdiff`, etc.)